# Centroid of a solid of revolution

Tags: calculus, centroid, solid-of-revolution

I am trying to calculate the centroid of the solid of revolution defined by $y=\sin (x)$ from $x=0$ to $x=\pi$ rotated around the $x$ axis. All the information I've been able to find online relates either to centroids of surface areas, or centroids of 2d areas. What is the formula for me to use here?

Comment: Think about the symmetry of the resulting solid.

Comment: The centroid is on the $y=0$ axis and along the $x$ at the location of symmetry,

Answer (score 3):

The centroid of any volume is defined by $$ \vec{c} = \frac{ \int \vec{r} \,{\rm d}V}{ \int {\rm d}V} $$

For a volume of revolution about  the *x*-axis ${\rm d}V = r\, {\rm d}\theta\, {\rm d}r \, {\rm d}x$ with the cross section (normal to the rev. axis) is described by the polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$. The location $\vec{r}$ of a small unit of volume is $$\vec{r} = \pmatrix{x \\ r \cos\theta \\ r \sin \theta}$$

In general, $r=0\ldots f(x)$ and $x=0\ldots a$ so the integral is

$$ \vec{c} = \frac{ \int \limits_{0}^{a} \int \limits_0^{f(x)} \int \limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} \vec{r}\,r\,{\rm d}\theta\,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}x }{\int \limits_{0}^{a} \int \limits_0^{f(x)} \int \limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} r\,{\rm d}\theta\,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}x} = \frac{ \int \limits_{0}^{a} \int \limits_0^{f(x)} \pmatrix{2\pi r\,x\\0\\0}  \,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}x }{\int \limits_{0}^{a} \int \limits_0^{f(x)} 2\pi\,r \,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}x} = \frac{ \int \limits_0^a \pmatrix{ x f^2(x) \\ 0 \\ 0}\,{\rm d}x}{ \int \limits_0^a f^2(x)\,{\rm d}x}$$

In your case $f(x)=\sin x$ and $a=\pi$

$$ \vec{c} = \frac{ \int \limits_0^\pi \pmatrix{ x \sin^2(x) \\0 \\0}\,{\rm d}x}{\int \limits_0^\pi \sin^2(x)\,{\rm d}x} = \frac{ \pmatrix{ \tfrac{\pi^2}{4} \\0 \\0}}{ \tfrac{\pi}{2}} = \pmatrix{ \frac{\pi}{2} \\0 \\0 } $$

PS. The indefinite integrals of $\int x \sin^2(x)\,{\rm d}x$ and $\int \sin^2(x)\,{\rm d}x$ need to be evaluated by parts, looked up on a table or use a CAS.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method is to use Pappus's ($2^{nd}$) Centroid Theorem: the volume of a planar area of revolution is the product of the area A and the length of the path traced by its centroid R, i.e., 2πR. When composite areas are involved, the centroid is the weighted sum of the component centroids. The bottom line is that the volume is given simply by V=2πRA.

For purpose of symmetry, I redefine your problem by shifting the axis so that  $y=\text{cos}(x)$ from $x=-\pi/2$ to $x=\pi/2$. Now, without any further ado, the centroid is at $R=\pi/8$ and the area under the curve is $A=2$. Then

$$V=2\pi RA=2\pi (\pi/8)2=\pi ^2/2 $$

Now granted, you need to calculate the centroid. And that's why I shifted the axis. Not many people know that for a symmetric function such as this the centroid can be expressed as the area of square of the curve, divided by the twice the are under the curve, i.e.,

$$R=\frac{\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\text{cos}^2 (x) dx}{2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\text{cos} (x) dx} $$

The point of this exercise is that you have a more general rule that can be applied to many problems, and not just an *ad hoc* solution to a single one.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
V
&=\pi\int_0^\pi y^2 \;\;dx\\
&= \pi\int_0^\pi \sin^2 x\;\; dx\\
&= \frac 12 \pi\int_0^\pi 1-\cos 2x\;\; dx\\
&=\frac 12 \pi \left[x-\frac{\sin 2x}2\right]_0^\pi\\
&=\color{red}{\frac {\;\pi^2}2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: User is trying to find centroid, not volume.